# Conectar ao DVR através do android

Tags: android, imagem

Preciso criar um projeto para estudo de como conectar a um DVR e receber as imagens através do android e estou meio perdido nessa busca, gostaria de alguma ajuda, oque devo estudar ou algum código de exemplo.

Para tentar esclarecer mais quero desenvolver para estudo algo como esse APP
[DVRplayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HBplayer)

ou esses existentes no [google play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dvr&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiBQoDZHZyegIYAIoBAggB)

Comment: O que é um DRV?

Comment: Desculpa falha minha é "DVR"